# iptables log ssh successful attempts that match known ips

Tags: ssh, iptables

I am unsure of how to log successful ssh attempts that match an IP address from GOOD_IPS. So far I am only logging incoming and outgoing attempts whether or not the related IP addresses are allowed or not. How would I write a statement that logs all successful SSH login attempts that match an address from GOOD_IPS and also one that logs successful and denied attempts from addresses outside of GOOD_IPS?

```
#allow ssh for ip addresses in GOOD_IPS chain
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --sport 22 -m state --state NEW -j GOOD_IPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 --syn -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: ssh outgoing attempt"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p TCP --sport 22 -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: ssh incoming attempt"
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j GOOD_IPS
iptables -A INPUT -p TCP --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
#ip addresses can be easily added 
iptables -A GOOD_IPS -s 192.168.182.132 -j ACCEPT
#iptables -A GOOD_IPS -s 232.28.25.86 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I think iptables can't know about ssh sucessfull logins. I think you must deal with sshd logins.

Comment: ill look into that, i suppose whats left is a statement that logs any attempt to login with an ip address from GOOD_IPS with the prefix "iptables: ssh login attempt - good_ips $IP_ADDRESS

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, as iptables cannot see the relevant data.

Something like `iptables -A INPUT -m string --string "SUCCESS" -j LOG` might have worked, were it not that SSH is encrypting this information, rendering it unusable for iptables.

Besides, all (succesful) attempts are already logged in `/var/log/secure` (or wherever your distribution onfigures this to be logged to). Why not look there?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Brigo that `iptables` is ill-suited to protocol-aware issues like logging successful logins; that's for `sshd`'s logging.  But you can log connection attempts with

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 22 -s a.b.c.d/e -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "ssh login attempt: "
```

where `a.b.c.d/e` is your good ip range, with mask (eg, `10.4.0.0/16`).

Comment: where you have -s a.b.c.d/e is it possible to point it to the GOOD_IPS to match any from the chain?

Comment: I don't know, it depends what's in the chain.  If you post the whole of the chain **in your question** (`iptables -L GOOD_IPS -n -v`), we can say whether it might be suitable for use like that.

Comment: If the chain fails with an error when the IPs are not good, then it won't return. So placing this `iptables` entry just after the call to the chain should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can know that with `iptables`. Although if SSH stays up *for a while*, it probably means it's a successful connection and thus authentication.

What you can use is `fail2ban`. That gives you access to the logs in a completely automated way. You can detect failures and block that IP if you'd like. Since it's written in Python, you can *easily* change the behavior and instead send an email or poke at another server, etc.

The version on Ubuntu 16.04 has a bug which makes [fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/) really slow at quitting if you have a large (thousands) number of blocked IPs. If you're not going to block anything, then you won't meet with that bug.

Once installed, look at this file for inspiration:

```
/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf
```

It probably won't be exactly what you want (since you want to signal positives and the default in fail2ban is to check for negatives...), but it should give you enough to get started.

There will be a small delay between the connection, log line written, detection by fail2ban, but it should still give you what you're looking for.